# Unable to access docker SimpleHTTPServer container

Tags: python, windows, docker, simplehttpserver

This question has been asked before, but I have not found a solution to my issue. I have some static files that I want to serve using Python's `SimpleHTTPServer` module. I have successfully built the image and run it, but I am unable to access the files from the browser. 
Here is my DockerFile:

```
FROM python:2.7

WORKDIR /test/
EXPOSE 8080

CMD python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

I am using the following commands:

```
docker build -t gwidgets/client-python-server . 
docker run --rm -ti -p 8080:8080 -v /gwt-polymer-starter/:/test/ --name client2 gwidgets/client-python-server
```

The image runs fine, but when I go to `http://{container'sIP}:8080/Test.html`, nothing happens. The server does not even get the request.

I am running docker on Windows 10.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: Docker for Windows, or Docker Machine? If it's Docker Machine you need to browse to the IP address of the VM which Docker Machine created (find it with `docker-machine ip`). Your Dockerfile works as expected on Linux, so it looks like a host/network issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Docker machine. After I run docker-machine ls, I picked the VM ip and used it, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The `-p` option publishes the container's ports to the host. You may need to use http://localhost:8080/Test.html if you run the container with `-p 8080:8080` specified.